# Cordova send SMS with plugin, not working URL on text

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugins, sms

I have a problem when I use Cordova 3.4 with [Plugin SMS](https://github.com/hazems/cordova-sms-plugin)
.
If I send a normal message it works well, but if I send a URL like http://maps.google.com/maps?z=18&q=123123,12312313, where I set my location to send to my user, it doesn't work.
The plugin "stops working" and doesn't give any "success" or "error".

I think there is a problem of illegal characters.

This is my code:

```
var coordinate="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=18&q="+lat+","+long+"";
var dateSos=new Date();
var hourSos = dateSos.getHours();
var minSos = dateSos.getMinutes();

text=text+".Hours "+hourSos+":"+minSos+". LAt: "+lat+" Long: "+long+" Alt: "+alt+". "+coordinate+""; //This messagge doesn't work
//text="Hello world"; This message will send without error
text=$.trim(text);

var messageInfo = {
  phoneNumber: number,
  textMessage: text
};
sms.sendMessage(messageInfo, function(message) {
   alert("success: " + message);

}, function(error) {
   alert("code: " + error.code + ", message: " + error.message);
});
```

"lat" and "long" are variables of my coordinate.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Show us your code and what you've done so far.

Comment: I edited the question entered my piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

The problem seems to be the **length of the character**, sms must have a maximum length of **160 characters**. If this length is exceeded, the plugin will not be any response.

Comment: thanks this was hard to debug..how did you find this out. Is there any way to increase this?

Comment: Actually this is wrong. I prematurely up voted. The issue I was experiencing was actually cause by something else. I've been sending messages of 177+ and everything is fine.

Comment: Seems like this is only true for Android sorry for the confusion. Using this plugin Android sms has 160 char limit.